# syntax error when trying to alter table column name mysql

Tags: mysql

I am working on a homework assignment. my instructions are this:

In the MATCHES table, change the column name MATCHNO to MATCH.

my syntax i wrote will be below, the problem I am having is with the word "match"
its giving me a syntax error of *unexpected syntax error* for it. I am assuming
that match is a keyword of some sort but after googling I'm not sure exactly.

the database I am using is the popular "tennis" one for teachings.

here is my code:

**sql**

```
ALTER TABLE MATCHES
CHANGE MATCHNO MATCH INT;
```

what can I do to fix this? If i change the name of "match" to something else it works but my instructions say to use "match"... is this possible?

Comment: Put the table and clumn names in backticks in order to prevent mysql interpret those as keywords.

Comment: As @MrTux stated, put the name in backticks. `MATCH` is a reserved mySQL word. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: @cookiemonster64 I formulated an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your query contains MySQL keywords (`MATCH`, cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

Put the table and column names in backticks (`) in order to prevent MySQL from interpreting those as keywords.

```
ALTER TABLE `MATCHES` CHANGE `MATCHNO` `MATCH` INT;
```